# Mathematica presentation mode

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm considering doing my next presentation in Mathematica instead of Keynote, and one thing I miss is Keynote's presentation mode -- when presenting it shows current slide on projector screen, while on laptop screen it shows current slide, next slide and timer. A work-around solution might be to convert Mathematica notebook to PDF, then convert PDF to KeyNote, but perhaps there's a better way?

Comment: Maybe you could dynamically hook up the positions of two notebooks. The main one on the projector and the secondary one on your laptop... I think the guy to ask would be http://www.scientificarts.com/worklife

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking, but perhaps you can find something useful here http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/computernotes.html

Answer (score 1):

There are wireless presentation devices that have built-in timers (they vibrate to alert you), but I've never witnessed anyone using a presentation remote with MMA. Interestingly, the Wolfram website claims support for presentation devices, but gives no specifics. [(here's my source)](http://www.wolfram.com/technology/guide/StreamlinedPresentationFramework/)  For devices listed below that lack built-in alarms, a possible workaround might be to include a *very subtle* dynamic clock or counter that you could toggle in and out of view --- I suppose you'd have to link a customizable button on the presenter device to a front-end token.

Here are some possibilities I researched for you:

1. [Logitech Professional Presenter R800 with Green Laser Pointer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002GHBUTU) However, I'm not sure how well it would work with MMA, as you generally need to be able to select and evaluate code, not just scroll through slides. Maybe you could include some 'Evaluate' buttons?
2. [SMK-Link RemotePoint Jade Laser Pointer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000SJHTXE) A more advanced wireless presenter that claims to offer four'fully programmable' shortcut keys (although user reviews seem to indicate the ENTER key isn't supported... uh, wtf?!?) If the user review is correct, and key combinations with ENTER aren't supported, might it be possible to assign a new custom evaluation key in MMA? I'm guessing it would be...
3. If you have money to burn, you might consider a wireless tablet device, such as: [Wacom Intuos4 Wireless Pen Tablet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0036WTX02) Pricy, but then you'd have a cool tablet for drawing, ink-based applications, etc. Also looks like it has customizable buttons that could be used to control evaluation.
4. Finally, might a wireless PlayStation controller work? I've never messed around with game pads in MMA, so I have no idea how customizable the buttons may or may not be...

If nobody else chimes in, this might be a good question to throw at the Wolfram Blog. (they recently started doing Q&A posts)